# Impact of Increasing GLIBC malloc() M_MMAP_THRESHOLD to 1GB

Tags: malloc, glibc

I am using **glibc (version 2.21)** for system with page size (2MB and 64MB). But with this very large page size, there is more fragmentation. So i increased the **M_MMAP_THRESHOLD** to 32MB using mallopt() still there is fragmentation. So i want to increase **M_MMAP_THRESHOLD** to 1 GB. Is there any impact of this on bin index calculation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was [answered on the libc-help list](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2018-09/msg00023.html):

If you increase `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`, you also have to increase the heap size to something like 32 GiB (`HEAP_MAX_SIZE` in malloc/arena.c).  The default of `2 * DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX` is probably too small (assuming that `DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX` will be 2 GiB).  Otherwise you will have substantial fragmentation for allocation requests between 2 GiB and `HEAP_MAX_SIZE`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for giving the answer so neatly, I am same guy who ask the answered for this question on libc-help.